# How to display information of a line chart by moving the mouse pointer over the chart area

Tags: vb.net

I have a desktop app in visual studio 2015 that has a line chart. I want to get the value of the (x,y) point when I move the mouse inside the chart area so I don't have to put every label because it will be flooded with labels and it would be a mess. The idea is to make a dot (or some kind of vertical and horizontal intersected line) to follow the X-position of the mouse pointer, but change the Y-position according to the Y-axis value.

The image below shows in a better way (I hope) what I'm looking for. You can see that the mouse pointer is in the chart area and there is a blue point (which I circled in red) that is in the X position of the mouse pointer and in the Y position of the Y-axis of the graph. Notice that it does not matter if it is above or under the line, the blue dot is in the line.

[image: Click here to see the image. I can't post embedded images yet.]

Now, the values of X and Y are shown above (in the inside the red rectangle). It would be nice to have those values in near the blue dot, like an annotation or something like that.

EDIT:
I managed to make some progress, but other problems appeared. I can put an annotation in the ChartArea2 (which is intended) but two things happens:

1) The annotation appears either I click the ChartArea1 or ChartArea2.
2) It creates two annotations instead of one.

The code I'm using is as follows.

To create the chart with the chart areas and the series:

```js
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim cargo As String = ComboBox1.Text
        Dim fi As Date = DateTimePicker1.Text
        Dim ff As Date = DateTimePicker2.Text
        Dim tabla As New DataTable
        Dim fechas As New DataTable
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim green As Integer
        Dim posX, posY, width, height As Single
        Dim numberOfAreas As Integer = 2


        green = RGB(118, 183, 3)

        cn.ConnectionString = ""
        Try
            tabla.Clear()
            fechas.Clear()

            Dim sql = ("select p.nombre, s.servicio_nombre, dp.etapa, dp.carga, fecha_inicial, fecha_final, extract (epoch from fecha_final - fecha_inicial)/86400 as duracion 
                        from desarrolloproyecto dp natural join cargo c natural join proyecto p natural join servicio s 
                        where nombre_cargo = '" & cargo & "' AND fecha_inicial BETWEEN '" & fi & "' AND '" & ff & "'
                        OR
                        nombre_cargo = '" & cargo & "' AND fecha_final BETWEEN '" & fi & "' AND '" & ff & "'
                        order by p.nombre desc")
            Dim sqlf = ("select t1.fechas, t1.carga from 
                        (select (generate_series(fecha_inicial, fecha_final, '1 day'::interval))::date AS fechas, sum(dp.carga) as carga
                        FROM desarrolloproyecto dp NATURAL JOIN cargo c NATURAL JOIN proyecto p NATURAL JOIN servicio s 
                        where  nombre_cargo = '" & cargo & "'
                        group by fechas
                        order by fechas)t1
                        where t1.fechas BETWEEN '" & fi & "' AND '" & ff & "'
                        order by t1.fechas")

            Dim da As New Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, cn)
            Dim daf As New Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter(sqlf, cn)

            cn.Open()
            da.Fill(tabla)
            daf.Fill(fechas)

            With Chart1
                .Series.Clear()
                .Series.Add("fechas")
                .Series.Add(cargo)
                .Series.Add("fech")
                .Series(cargo).ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
                .Series("fechas").ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
                .Series("fech").ChartArea = "ChartArea2"




                .Legends("Legend1").Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                .Legends("Legend1").Docking = Docking.Bottom
                .Series("fechas").IsVisibleInLegend = False
                .Series("fech").IsVisibleInLegend = False
                .Series("fechas").Color = Color.Transparent
                .Series(cargo).Color = Color.FromArgb(118, 183, 3)
                .Series(cargo).CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle = Cylinder"
                .Series("fech").Color = Color.FromArgb(118, 183, 3)

                .Series("fech").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
                .Series("fechas").ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar
                .Series(cargo).ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar

                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Position = New ElementPosition(0, 0, 95, 70)
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").CursorX.IsUserEnabled = True
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = True
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = True
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = False
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").CursorY.IsUserEnabled = True
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = True
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = True
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = False
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Minimum = fi.ToOADate 'valores minimos y maximos de ejes x e y
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Maximum = ff.ToOADate
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 1

                
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea2").Position = New ElementPosition(0, 70, 95, 25)
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea2").CursorX.IsUserEnabled = True
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea2").CursorY.IsUserEnabled = True
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea2").AxisX.Minimum = fi.ToOADate
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea2").AxisX.Maximum = ff.ToOADate
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea2").AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto



                .Series("fech").SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = True


                For k = 0 To tabla.Rows.Count - 1
                    .Series("fechas").Points.AddXY(tabla.Rows(k).Item(0) & "-" & tabla.Rows(k).Item(1) & "-E" & tabla.Rows(k).Item(2), tabla.Rows(k).Item(4))
                    .Series(cargo).Points.AddY(tabla.Rows(k).Item(6))
                Next

                For k = 0 To fechas.Rows.Count - 1
                    .Series("fech").Points.AddXY(fechas.Rows(k).Item(0), fechas.Rows(k).Item(1))
                    If k = 0 Then
                        posY = fechas.Rows(0).Item(1)
                        posX = fechas.Rows(0).Item(1)
                    Else
                        posY = Min(posY, fechas.Rows(k).Item(1))
                        posX = Max(posX, fechas.Rows(k).Item(1))
                    End If

                Next
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea2").AxisY.Minimum = posY - 25
                .ChartAreas("ChartArea2").AxisY.Maximum = posX + 25
                


            End With
            Label1.Focus()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Now, for the annotation part it goes as follows:

```js
Private Sub Chart1_CursorPositionChanging(sender As Object, e As CursorEventArgs) Handles Chart1.CursorPositionChanging

        
        Dim a As CalloutAnnotation = New CalloutAnnotation()
        a.AnchorDataPoint = Chart1.Series("fech").Points(0)
        a.Text = "Select this Annotation Object\nand move the Anchor point"
        Chart1.Annotations.Add(a)

    End Sub
```

So I guess I have 3 questions now.

1) How can I make the annotations appear only when I move the mouser over the ChartArea2? (The idea is not to click the ChartArea2.

2) How can I make only to appear one annotation?

3) How can I make the annotation move when I move the mouse pointer along the X-axis? I would like that the annotation coordenates were x = mouse pointer value and y = y-axis value.